# shortest/easiest way to reconstruct map<key, value> into map<value, key>

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

If I have static `map<K, V> m{{"m1", 1}, {"m2", 2}, ...}` which is the easiest way to convert it to `map<V, K>` with the same pairs, but now values goes to keys, and keys to values?

I want to have this in class initialization code. Like that:

```
class PseudoEnum{
   enum Enum{m1, m2, m3};
   static map<string, Enum> _strMapping = {{"m1", Enum::m1}, {"m2", Enum::m2}, ...};
   static map<Enum, string> _enumMapping = ??? // shortest possible init  
}
```

Comment: What do you want to have happen if the map contains multiples of the same values?

Comment: that's not possible. I have it enum to string mapping

Comment: Then just iterate. Should be like three lines of code. What am I missing?

Comment: @Natasha Post a more complete example please!

Comment: boost bimap may help with this. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Yes a bimap will be appropriate if you need _both_ views, not just to convert one to the other at a single time.

Comment: I updated question. Can't use bimap since boost not used on a project

Comment: I think there's a fairly important distinction beteen shortest and fastest init.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::transform(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), std::inserter(other, other.begin()),
               [](auto const& p){
    return std::make_pair(p.second, p.first);
});
```

This should be enough. You can wrap it in a function:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
auto invert_mapping(std::map<K,V> const& m)
{
    std::map<V,K> other;
    std::transform(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), std::inserter(other, other.begin()),
                   [](auto const& p){
        return std::make_pair(p.second, p.first);
    });
    return other;
}
```

then you would call

```
static map<Enum, string> _enumMapping = invert_mapping(_strMapping);
```

If you want to initialize it in-place, you can make use of Boost's transform iterator:

```
auto tr = [](auto const& p){ return std::make_pair(p.second, p.first); };
std::map<Enum, std::string> _enumMapping(
    boost::make_transform_iterator(_strMapping.cbegin(), tr),
    boost::make_transform_iterator(_strMapping.cend(), tr)
);
```

Comment: I prefer the term `invert_mapping` to `reverse_key_value`. This relates to [inverse mappings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) in math.

Comment: @erip I was really unsure how to call it so I went with naive but still fairly clear. Thanks, edited.